# Copy the title of the active window to the clipboard in Microsoft Windows in Dragon NaturallySpeaking's advanced scripting

Tags: naturallyspeaking

Is there any way to copy the title of the active window to the clipboard in Microsoft Windows in Dragon NaturallySpeaking's advanced scripting?

A workaround I use is to define an [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script:

```
^!l::
WinGetActiveTitle, Title
Clipboard = %Title%
return
```

and call the keyboard shortcut in the voice command:

[image]

but I would prefer not to have to jungle it between AutoHotkey and Dragon NaturallySpeaking. Can it be done in "pure" advanced scripting?

Comment: The answer is yes (I will post how shortly) but in the meantime, you can use advanced scripting to call up AHK scripts using "ShellExecute" to run an AHK script without having to trigger any hotkey (and you can even pass AHK some command line parameters).  Check out http://www.knowbrainer.com/forums/forum/messageview.cfm?catid=25&threadid=22676&discTab=true&messid=130757&parentid=130734&FTVAR_FORUMVIEWTMP=Single  (and note, PG LTU is me).

Comment: @PGilm Thanks, very good to know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can copy the title of the active window to the clipboard using Dragon NaturallySpeaking's advanced scripting as follows:

```
'
'   get window title
'
Sub Main
    Clipboard ( GetWindowTitle )
End Sub
'
'   Use these Windows Functions for Getting an active Window title
'
Declare Function GetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" () As Long
'
Declare Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" _
    Alias "GetWindowTextA" ( ByVal hwnd As Long , _
        ByVal lpString As String , ByVal cch As Long ) As Long
'
'   GetWindowTitle
'   (Gets an active Window title)
'
Function GetWindowTitle() As String
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim TitleText As String * 300
    Dim hw As Long
    hw = GetForegroundWindow()
    x = GetWindowText ( hw , TitleText , Len ( TitleText ) )
    GetWindowTitle = Trim ( Left ( TitleText , x ) )
End Function
'
```

Now, I keep all the functions in a global '#Uses file (with other declarations, functions and global constants, etc.), so I just need the Main Sub part, but you can put all of  the referenced functions and declarations in the one script where you need it, too.

Hth